# How to trap a SIGNAL in a java application initialized using a bash script

Tags: java, bash, jvm, signals

I am catching an INT signal in java using the following code:

```
    Signal.handle(new Signal("INT"), new SignalHandler () {
        public void handle(Signal sig) {

            log.warn("Received SIGINT signal. Will teardown.");

            task.tearDown();

            // Force exit anyway
            System.exit(1);
        }
      });
```

When I am using `java -jar file.jar` to start my application I can catch the signal sent with with `kill -INT PID`.

If I call `java -jar file.jar &`  (jvm runs in the background), I can't catch the signal sent with `kill -INT`.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the java process do when you use kill -INT? Does it terminate, or keep running?

Answer (score 3):

Works for me. Are you sure you are killing the right pid? On Unix you can use `$!` to get the pid of the last process you launched.

```
$ java -jar file.jar &
[1] 25573

$ kill -INT $!
Received SIGINT signal. Will teardown.
```

**Update:**

If you are launching this in the background via a shell script, the OS will create a new process group which will be immune to keyboard-generated signals such as SIGINT. Only processes whose process group ID matches the current terminal's process group ID can receive these signals.

So try running it within the current terminal's process group like this:

```
. ./script.sh
```

You will then be able to send SIGINT.

More information about job control [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control-Basics).

Comment: That works for me. What doesn't work is catching the signal inside an application started from inside a bash script file.

Comment: @simao - how your bash script file launches the java program will be important.  Is your java program a daemon?  How are the two processes related (the bash script and the java program)?

Comment: The java program is not a daemon and runs using 2 threads. The java app is executed using java -jar file.jar & inside a .sh file. Thanks.

Comment: To forward the SIGINT from the terminal to the java process without having to match the process group, you need to literally forward it by trapping it in the script and killing the process. This is what i usually do:
java -jar app.jar & ; pid=$! ; trap "echo \"now killing java\"; kill $pid && exit 0" SIGTERM SIGINT ; wait

Answer (score 0):

I going to guess the bash script is ignoring SIGINT and the child is inheriting the signal mask.

Look in the bash script for something like this. (There may be more numbers than just 2.)

```
trap "" 2
```

The empty string causes the shell to set SIG_IGN. If instead you use:

```
trap ":" 2
```

That registers a handler that does nothing. When a child process is started, any signal with a handler installed is reset to SIG_DFL.