# When is control CTRL+C ignored

Tags: java, exception

I have a java application which is implemented as a main method, with a try, catch finally block. The work is done inside the try. If I kick of the application via a bash script, and during its execution issue a `CTRL+C`, I'm noticing inconsistent behaviour. Sometimes the catch block executes and sometimes it does not. Can this be explained?

(sample code below - where sometimes neither "Caught" or "Shutdown Complete" are logged)

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
      doStuff();
       } catch (Throwable e) {
          LOGGER.error("Caught.", e);
       } finally {
          LOGGER.info("Shutdown complete.");
       }
    }  
}
```

Comment: This is `C` or `Java`?

Comment: Wow. Please share some code. This depends on exactly where in the execution the SIGINT is sent...

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera it's java, he means the key combination of CTRL+C

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera the tag says java.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP doesn't provide code which related to the issue, without code can't answer.

Comment: Does your main method run in a loop ? I agree with other comments - please post the code....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147288/how-to-trap-a-signal-in-a-java-application-initialized-using-a-bash-script

Comment: As requested by others, please share code _and_ the stack trace as well. You do not even tell what exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [finally documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html), the JVM gives does not guarantee that the finally block is executed:

*If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed, then the finally block may not execute. Likewise, if the thread executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally block may not execute even though the application as a whole continues.*

Thus you can not rely on the finally block.
If you need to catch the CTRL-C event, you'd better use a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/hook-design.html).

Comment: Makes sense re finally. However, should I expect that the catch block is invoked? Thanks

Comment: In order to invoke the catch block, the CTRL-C event must trigger off a throwable. This is not the case, at least for the Oracle's JVM. According to my tests and documentation (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/signals-139944.html#gbzcv), this signal just terminates the process. Once again, the recommended way to handle it "gracefully" is using a shutdown hook. It is really easy to set up. Just give it a try.